# Huawei Y9 Pro camera issues

Tags: huawei

I've recently got a Huawei Y9 prime and I hope it will have good quality in videos. But unexpectedly there are not very clear as I expected. I mean all of the videos have a wave-like effect on it. Is it a problem with the camera? 
Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Dude, it's because of more added grain and smoothing the grain making it look like low textured pic, but if you want to know a temporary fix then download Adobe light room to take pics and edit them just by pressing auto(in the edit menu) and then going to effects or details to increase the texture as per your liking.
I also have a huawei y9 prime 2019 and wasn't expecting that, but by some research (a lot) I was able to get a news that it will be with the help of some upcoming updates... 
So we gotta wait until then.

Hope the temporary solution helps